Docker: The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 14, which is not compatible with this version 15.7 (Debian 15.7-1.pgdg120+1)
Above mentioned, is the error I am getting while running my postgres service among other services in my compose.yaml file.
To let you know the change I made,
I just changed the version from postgres:14 to postgres:15.
I have created volume called postgres-data and it was existing since I was using postgres 14.
volumes:
  postgres-data:
    name: postgres-data
  pgadmin-data:
    name: pgadmin-data

This is how it is defined currently (only change was from 14 to 15)
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgres/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

My question is, what is the preferred way ahead

Should we delete the older volume postgres-data by going into Docker Desktop -> Volumes ?
or Should we create a new volume with separate name and mount it for postgres container ?

Thank you for reading, I am looking for expert advise on how people from DevOps world deal with this issue.

data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.0 suggests dumping the data from the old database version, deleting the data directory, and restoring the dump; does that work?  Note that Stack Overflow is specifically about programming questions, and there are specific other [devops.se] and [dba.se] sites.

@DavidMaze Thanks for sharing that link. I had skimmed through the first initial answers but didn't got the one I was expecting.
Nice to know that there is dedicated sites for asking such questions.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/upgrading.html

The data between version 14 and 15 are not compatible; there are 2 scenarios, and many solutions:
Scenario 1: Data IS important
The data should be converted from version 14 to version 15.

Revert the Postgres image change in compose.yaml back to 14 and start docker compose with docker compose up -d

Backup all with pg_dumpall to dump your data before removing the files:
example: pg_dumpall -U postgres > db.sql

Then you can copy that db.sql backup file to your host (by mounting in a volume)

Change the volume name in your compose.yaml to postgres-new-data

Finally, start docker compose with docker compose up -d, and restore with pg_restore.


Note: You can also remove the volume with docker volume rm postgres-data, but it would be better to keep everything as a backup, before having the new one.
You can also remove the data (keeping the directory itself) in /var/lib/postgres/, but again, it would be good to keep everything until we are stable with the new version.

Use pg_upgrade to upgrade the data.

Scenario 2: Data IS NOT important

Just stop Compose with docker compose down, and remove the volume with docker volume rm postgres-data.
Start again with docker compose up -d.

